# PostgreSQL COPY - Generated columns cannot be used in COPY

Tags: postgresql, restore, copy

Im trying to import a SQL dump file for a table (A COPY command dump file). The table has a generated column. While restoring the dump Im getting this error.

```
ERROR:  column "call_status" is a generated column
DETAIL:  Generated columns cannot be used in COPY.
```

How do I bypass this error?

PostgreSQL version: 12

#### Sample copy command

```
COPY test_revision (acc_id,revision,status) FROM STDIN;
acc-001  5  pass
acc-002  4  pending
```

the status column is a generated column based on revision id.

```
If revision 5 then status column value would be pass
```

Comment: Works for me. Can you show us the **exact** code you are running (**[edit]** your question, do not post code in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have modified the question.

Comment: Ah, _that_ kind of generated columns (I assumed "identity" using "generated always"). Well, there is no way around it other than, **not** providing the generated columns during insert. `COPY test_revision (acc_id,revision) FROM STDIN;` and then providing only two column in the input data. Or better: normalize your data and put the `status` column into a table.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the workaround.